# three.js webgl mesh materials get the same color as canvas background

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, three.js

Well I'm new with three.js and I can't understand why is this happening and if it is normal. Here are my renderer settings:

```
if ( !webglSupported() ) {
    throw new Error("WebGL not supported!");
}

var defaults = {

    init :{
        antialias: (isDesktop)(), 
        alpha: true,
        maxLights: 4
    },

    clearColor: 0x000000,
    clearColorIntensity: 1,
    autoClear: true,
    sortObjects : true

};

this.options.renderer = $.extend( true, defaults, settings );

this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( this.options.renderer.init );

if ( "autoClear" in this.options.renderer ) {
    this.renderer.autoClear = this.options.renderer.autoClear;
}

if ( "sortObjects" in this.options.renderer ) {
    this.renderer.sortObjects = this.options.renderer.sortObjects;
}

this.renderer.setClearColor( this.options.renderer.clearColor, this.options.renderer.clearColorIntensity );
this.renderer.setSize( this.options.generic.container.clientWidth, this.options.generic.container.clientHeight );

this.options.generic.container.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
```

canvas background is set to blue (#00f), and here are my materials:

```
var backgroundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xefefef,
    specular: 0x3399ff,
    //emissive : 0xefefef,
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    overdraw: false,
    transparent: false,
    metal:true,
    shininess: this.options.models.boxShininess,
    reflectivity: this.options.models.boxReflectivity,
    fog:false
});


var productMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: productModelTexture,
    color: 0xefefef,
    specular: 0x3399ff,
    //emissive : 0xefefef, 
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    overdraw: false,
    transparent: false,
    metal:true,
    shininess: that.options.models.textureShininess,
    reflectivity: that.options.models.textureReflectivity,
    opacity: 1,
    fog:false
});
```

Also keep in mind that everything takes place inside a blue sphere / dome, but the dome has no affect on those objects.

Why when I change canvas css background the same color is being applied to productMaterial and backgroundMaterial  ?|

**UPDATE**

After some digging I found out that if you set the transparency of the material to true (in this case productMaterial), then it solves the problem. I'm still not sure if this is the correct approach thoough.

PS: the texure is a 512x512 png with an transparency in various sections, those sections used to appear as the same color as the canvas css background color.

Comment: Even though this is great programming it does not help with debugging. All your values are hidden behind `this.options`. What would happen if you cleared the renderer to green? Does the blue canvas disappear? Also you are using `this` for background and `that` for product. Dont know your code to assume if it correct.

Comment: that is being used because product material is being generated inside a callback. outside of the callback that = this.Check my latest update regarding the issue.

Comment: I meant that each cube has different texture hence the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found out that if you set the transparency of the material to true (in this case productMaterial), then it solves the problem. I'm still not sure if this is the correct approach thoough.

PS: the texure is a 512x512 png with an transparency in various sections, those sections used to appear as the same color as the canvas css background color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing now, but is the sphere that this is happening in so large, that it exceeds the far plane of its frustrum?

For instance:

```
var cam = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, W / H, 1, 1000);
var dome = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(1000),
  material
);
```

would create a sphere that (if positions haven't been changed) would go beyond the camera frustrum and will get cleared with the clear color.